# Import file name into list box without path access 2007 vba-

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating a database where users can click a command button, they will be taken to a folder that is stored in a trusted location and they can choose a word document from there and all the names of chosen files will show in a list box on a form. We have the code to double click the file name to open the document. What we are looking  for is code to show only the file name in the list box without the path.

We have used the sample code given in the question "How to show open file dialogue in access 2007 vba" from this site to set this up so far.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Ta Tony,
             I can't seem to get that to work: here is our code at the moment. On clicking the command button the File Dialog opens and executes,public function trims it to be only the file name DblClick opens the selected object from the list box.
Our problem now is that the file name has trimmed the path and can not be opened from the double click. We have got it working right up to this point.

Answer (score 3):

Execute the following code for each file name to be inserted into the list box.

```
Dim Chunks() As String, DocumentName As String
Chunks() = Split("\\server\share\folder\subfolder\docuemnt.doc", "\")
DocumentName = Chunks(UBound(Chunks()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FileSystemObject to quickly get the filename part

> EDIT - good suggestion from BitAccesser

Requires a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime, or you need to use the `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`

```
Const WORD_TEST_PATH    As String = "C:\users\admin\test\test.doc"

Dim fso             As New FileSystemObject
Dim strWordFileName As String

strWordFileName = fso.GetFileName(WORD_TEST_PATH)
Debug.Print strWordFileName
```

> Output is: test.doc

Just replace WORD_TEST_PATH with the filename returned from your Dialog path

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Isn't `FileSystemObject` state of the art (e.g.: easy to get filename,path,type,dates,etc..)?

Comment: Appreciate the cancellation of it @BitAccesser. I wouldn;t worry about it. I've seen some weird things. All I could think of was that I named the variable as constant - but thought it was better than hardcoding in the GetFileName call. I any case I thought it was a good basic example of FSO. I use it frequently. It's powerful and easy to use.

Comment: As I am new and enthusiastic (we will see how long), I will hold the line and complain about that ;)

Comment: Maybe someone stumbled over the missing reference for `FSO` (Microsoft Scripting Runtime), you should mention that or switch to late binding.